# Structuring Cassandra tables for high speed queries

Tags: cassandra

We are looking at using Cassandra for storing data for a clinical trial.  The data is essentially oxygen saturation and respiration rate (and a few other things).  We also need to store a patient identifier, visit code and facility code.  We expect to only need to retrieve data by unique patient/visit.  However each patient could have 500,000+ records.  There could be 1000's of patients and maybe 100 facilities.  My question relates to the design of the table(s) to ensure rapid retrieval of data:

```
Create table OxygenSats
    (
        facility int,
        visit text,
        pat_id text,
        probe_id text
        event timestamp,
        oxygen float,
        resp int,
        Primary key((facility, visit), pat_id)
    );
```

From this, I think data will be clustered on pat_id and partitioned on (facility, visit).  Is this correct?  Read speed is very important.  We will need to select by patient (essentially facility, visit, patient) and filter by date.

Is this an optimal approach for the type of data we are dealing with?  Any guidance / advice appreciated.

The queries we need are reasonably simple - we just need to select all the data for a patient (filtering on date would be useful as well):

```
select oxygen, resp from OxygenSats where facility = '1', and visit = '1' and pat_id = '22'
```

Comment: It would help if you could write the CQL queries you want to make in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your thinking that it is partitioned on the composite key of (facility, visit) and clustered on pat_id. The uniqueness of visit here is critical but not specified, right now we can't tell if visit is globally unique per visit of a patient or not. Some more details on the select queries would also be useful, will they include ranges or just point queries?

Once thing you can do is benchmark it using NoSQLBench [Github Repo](https://github.com/nosqlbench/nosqlbench/releases/tag/nosqlbench-3.12.138) and [Docs](http://docs.nosqlbench.io/#/docs/) - this will give you a good idea of performance ahead of use.

The upper recommended partition size limit is 100 Mb, so you can do some calculations around data sizes and record numbers per partition to ascertain whether your key is going to cause you a partition size problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  The facility,visit, patient_id combination would be globally unique, but have a one to many relationship with the oxygen data.  Visit would have a many to one relationship with patient_id - a patient can have multiple visits.  On a rough calculation, 1 month of data at 5 second samples is around 8Mb - so the size limit should be ok.  Thank you for the suggestion of bench marking

Comment: Ok, so your primary key is not itself primary, for a single patient visiting a facility - they have multiple readings - your PK currently does not create primality of that reading record - you need to make sure the PK really is a PK.

Comment: of course... so I need to define another unique per row key

Comment: Yes, extend the clustering columns to make sure it's unique.

Comment: I guess a UUID would be fit for purpose?

Comment: I think this might work:  Forget pat_id - its not needed.  (facility, visit) is the partition key as this is unique for a group.  Then use the timestamp as a timeuuid  as a cluster key within the partition.

Comment: As long as  the partition / clustering then satisfies the query needs.